# class binding not updating font awesome 5 class in angular

Tags: angular, font-awesome

component.ts

```
component.html
import { faStar, faStarHalf, faStarHalfStroke } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'favourite',
  templateUrl: './favourite.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./favourite.component.css']
})
export class FavouriteComponent implements OnInit {
  isFave: boolean;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onClick() {
    this.isFave = !this.isFave;
    console.log(this.isFave);
  }
}
```

```
<div class="icon" (click)="onClick()">
    <span
    class="fa-star" 
    [class]="isFave ? 'fa-solid':'fa-regular'"
    ></span>
</div>
```

component.css

```
svg{
    pointer-events: all;
}
```

The code will return a outlined on click when I remove the fa-regular from the second statement in the html file and toggles correctly back and forth and if I add it in it shows the fa-regular icon on load toggle will not work with... tried adding pointer-events still updates class to : class="svg-inline--fa fa-star" on load instead of fa-star fa-solid...

Comment: Use [NgClass]..?

Comment: Yeah tried that too. It has something to do with the click() not working any more as version 4 works i believe the way it uses an svg in the child it causes maybe the div above not to react to clicks once the svg is loaded but i tried adding css to ignore this problem to no avail maybe I'll try adding that pointer-events: all; to a * css class *{ ]

Comment: i found a post that may work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47852705/fontawesome-5-on-click-event i dont know how i missed it i searched for solutions all day yesterday... but did not know the meat of whats was causing the issue.

Comment: may try stopPropagation(); IDK if it will work since it happens after the bubbling.